# how to make mongo filter data with group concat like sql

Tags: mongodb

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(salary) FROM user GROUP BY employee WHERE leave = ''

db.user.aggregate(
   [
      {
        "$group" : {
                "_id" : "$employee", total: { "$push": "$salary" }
            }
      },
      {
        "$match" : { "leave" : '' }
      }
   ]
)
```

Here i am trying to fetch data from  mongodb by filtering and group concat.

Above is the sql query and what i have tried with but, that didn't work.

PLease have a look

Comment: You actually mean to have the `$match` stage **first** here. A `$match` after a `$group` would only be valid for a `HAVING` type of operation, and in fact as *"good SQL"* the statement should read `SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(salary) FROM user WHERE leave = '' GROUP BY employee` in terms of it's logical execution.

Comment: You should also see [SQL to Aggregation Mapping Chart](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/sql-aggregation-comparison/) in the core MongoDB documentation. It contains many common examples, whether you are acquainted with SQL or not.